# Using wordpress shortcodes to render PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a shortcode to render custom php pages. I'm getting very odd behaviour which i'm not getting if I used a wordpress template.

For example. If i create a template with the code:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?> <?php generate_article_schema( 'BlogPosting' ); ?>>
<div class="inside-article">
<?PHP $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() );

    global $post;
    $post_info = get_post($post->ID);
    $content =  $post_info->post_content;

    $ind = strrpos($content, "/");

    $page = substr($content, $ind+1);
    $path = substr($content, 0, $ind+1);

   $oldDir = getcwd();
   chdir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$path);
   include($page);
   chdir($oldDir);

?>


</div><!-- .inside-article -->
</article><!-- #post-## -->
```

Then in the wordpress page i simply enter the location of the file, e.g. /contact/contact_form.php. The contact_form.php page renders on the screen within the wordpress theme.

Now, i recently discovered shortcodes, and thought these would be a better way of rendering the php on the page. Instead of having the content of the page as /contact/contact_form.php I could have [custom_php filepath="/contact/contact_form.php"]

This is where i'm getting problems. The contact_form.php seems to have many require_once() functions all over the place, yet the variables wtihin them don't seem to exist, even though the first method (above) works fine.

For my shortcode code I have:

```
function subscribe_custom_php_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
$atts = shortcode_atts(
    array(
        'filepath' => '/index.php'
    ), $atts);


    $ind = strrpos($atts["file"], "/");
    $page = substr($atts["file"], $ind+1);
    $path = substr($atts["file"], 0, $ind+1);
    $oldDir = getcwd();
    chdir($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].$path); 
    ob_start();
    include($page); 
    $content = ob_get_clean();      
    chdir($oldDir);
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('custom_php', 'subscribe_custom_php_shortcode');
```

As you can see, the code is very similar except I added ob_start() and ob_get_clean() to get the results of the PHP based on someones comments. Removing these still doesn't seem to bring back the values of the require_conce within the contact_form.php.

What's interesting is if i change the require_once for include it works.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a template you bought or default wp theme?

Comment: A template I wrote myself as above

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `filepath` is relative to theme directory, this should be the best way to include it...

```
function subscribe_custom_php_shortcode($atts, $content = null) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'filepath' => '/index.php'
        ), $atts );

    ob_start();
    include get_stylesheet_directory() . $atts['filepath'];
    $content = ob_get_clean();

    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('custom_php', 'subscribe_custom_php_shortcode');
```

As you can see... we use the `get_stylesheet_directory` function to get the current theme directory.

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi, thanks but I don't think the issue is the path of the include file but includes within those files

Comment: When using this shortcode... do you get an error or it didn't work the way you expected?